# How to copy one directory with all content using nant script?

Tags: build, automation, copy, release, nant

I need to copy one folder with all content.

My folder structure is like this

`Main Folder`

`folder1`

```
`1.zip`
`2.zip`
```

`Folder2`

```
`3.zip`
`4.zip`
```

How to copy main folder with all these content using nant script.

Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<copy todir="newDir">
  <fileset basedir="oldDir">
     <include name="**/*" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: how can we pass variables from c#.net to this xml by giving the newDir and oldDir values?